# Ubuntu mv pwd command

Tags: command-line, 16.04, search

I tried to move a file from one directory to another using this command in the terminal:

```
mv ~/file.txt pwd
```

In that moment i was in non-system hard drive. Later i wasn't able to find my file in that directory. Ok, i created symlink to another file using

```
ln -s file2.txt myLink
```

and repeated the mv operation. Again, there was no file in pwd folder. More than that, i can't get the location of file using symlink. I've tried

```
ls -ld myLink
```

and it gives me

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myName myName 8 may  9 22:20 myLink -> file2.txt
```

readlink command just prints file2.txt in terminal.

Is there any chances to find my file or it was deleted? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Are you sure the command `mv ~/file.txt pwd` didn't just create *a file named pwd* in the directory where you ran it?

Comment: So i had to write something link mv ~/file.txt pwd/file.txt? Ye, i can see pwd file.. But is there any way to restore file.txt?

Comment: just `mv -v pwd file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first, your command for moving something to your current working directory should have been:

```
mv ~/file.txt "$(pwd)"
```

or

```
mv ~/file.txt "$PWD"
```

You can search for your file by using the find command (sudo is necessary for searching the whole computer):

```
sudo find / -name "file.txt"
```

Advice if you're not sure if your command is working like it should try a `cp` first and not a `mv`.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. More than that, it was my first using of moving/copying files command with usage of pwd. Fortunately, i have a backup of that file. Thanks for help :)